Rescuing ZFS after Debian upgrade
So I had older Debian system which needed to be upgraded. I did dist-upgrade, but forgot I am running ZFS on a root partition. :/ Result: system won't boot again. Because I would need to manually build ZFS kernel modules...
So I booted Debian 12 live and created sysroot directory:
sudo mkdir /sysroot
Then I said:
sudo zpool import -N rpool
sudo zfs load-key rpool <-- I entered my password
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/sysroot rpool
sudo zpool status <-- this one says rpool is ONLINE
sudo zfs get encryption,keystatus
I get this:
NAME PROPERTY YALUE SOURCE
rpool encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool keystatus available -
rpool/ROOT encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/ROOT keystatus available -
rpool/ROOT/Adebian encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/ROOT/debian keystatus available -
rpool/swap encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/swap keystatus available -
rpool/virt encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/virt keystatus available -
rpool/virt/debiantest encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/virt/debiantest keystatus available -
rpool/virt/test-debian encryption aes-256-gcm -
rpool/virt/test-debian keystatus available -

Now I look into /sysroot, but it is empty!
But sudo zfs get mountpoint says:
NAME PROPERTY YALUE SOURCE
rpool mountpoint  /sysroot local
rpool/ROOT mountpoint none local
rpool/ROOT/debian mountpoint / local
rpool/swap mountpoint - -
rpool/virt mountpoint none local
rpool/virt/debiantest mountpoint - -
rpool/virt/test-debian mountpoint - -

And when I say sudo systemd-nspawn -b -D /sysroot, it says: Directory /sysroot doesn't look like an OS root directory (os-release file is missing). Refusing.
So, what I am doing wrong?

Note the mountpoint of rpool/ROOT/debian in the zfs get mountpoint listing:
NAME PROPERTY YALUE SOURCE
rpool mountpoint  /sysroot local
rpool/ROOT mountpoint none local
rpool/ROOT/debian mountpoint / local
rpool/swap mountpoint - -
[...]

It looks like you may have not previously used the "top level" of the rpool for anything: your existing root filesystem seems to have been the rpool/ROOT/debian dataset.
You might want to do:
zfs set mountpoint=none rpool
zfs set mountpoint=/sysroot rpool/ROOT/debian

